# A carwash is for clean up

Tags: grammar

1. A carwash is for clean up.
2. A carwash is for cleaning up.

Is #1 corrct to say? 
(A carwash where you take your car for clean up(cleaning up)

Comment: _Cleanup_ (a single word) is a noun with the meaning _the act or process of removing a dirty or dangerous substance, esp. when it has been left in the environment as a result of an accident_ (see [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cleanup)) and is not synonymous with the gerund _cleaning._

Comment: A *car wash* is for washing your car. It is pretty clear.

Comment: As user3169 points out _car wash_ consists of two separate words in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A car wash is for cleaning your car." Or : "A car wash is (a place) where you take your car to be cleaned."

You use of the terms "cleanup" and "cleaning up" are both incorrect.

As PE Dant points out, "cleanup" is a process of dealing with environmental pollution, such as an oil spill.

You use "cleaning up" when you are referring to the mess which has been made. So you could say "I am cleaning up after having a party" or you could say "A mop and bucket are used for cleaning up the mud from the kitchen floor."

You use "clean" on its own without the "up" when you are referring to a space or object, rather than the mess or dirt on or in it. So you clean the kitchen or the windows, or you clean the car.

http://www.phrasemix.com/answers/whats-the-difference-between-clean-away-clean-up-clean-out-e

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct (and why both of the OP's alternatives are not); answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.